# Basic behaivor of container class for high resolution iphone

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="container">
```

I have simple container class.

I read the documents and understand.

It has both side spacing for PC screen, and it has full width for mobile screen.

However in my iphone simulator, it dosen't become full width, it remains spacing both side.

(I guess it is because of iPhone high resolution??)

If I use `container-fluid`, it becomes full-width on iPhone Sim.

I want to have with spacing on PC and full for mobile.

What is the best practice???

Comment: You can also use media quires to customize devices layout as you want

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a `meta` tag with `viewport` inside your `<head>` tag.
This tells smaller device browsers how to scale the page.
It is more explained here.
https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag--webdesign-5972

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: @whitebear i am glad i could help. If this solves your problem you can accept my answer so it will be helpful for others in future too.  
Happy Coding !!